# Android Wear: AVD Create Error: unknown skin name 'AndroidWearRound' and 'AndroidWearSquare'

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I've been trying to make a simple default android wear app by myself, and then by following these intructions: http://www.sitepoint.com/hands-android-wear-developer-sdk/.

At the point where I hit the "Start..." and then "Launch" button in the AVD manager for the Wear VD that I named 'watch', I get this error (same with Square):

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'watch'
emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'AndroidWearRound'
```

[image: AVD Error]

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tbse.wearapp"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  wearApp project(':wear')
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
  // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.+'
}
```

I think I have all the right things installed from the SDK Manager.

[image: SDK Manager]
[image: SDK Manager - Support]

How do I import this round or square skin?

---

Responding to Wayne Piekarski's answer:

I opened AVD through Android Studio and deleted my watch emulators. I opened the SDK manager and deleted and re-installed API 20 4.4W. Then I tried from the command line, and it still can't find the skin:

```
toddbsmithmbp:tools tbsmith$ pwd
/Applications/Android Studio Beta.app/sdk/tools
toddbsmithmbp:tools tbsmith$ ./android create avd --force -n WatchSquare --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Square" --skin AndroidWearSquare --abi     android-wear/armeabi-v7a
Created AVD 'WatchSquare' based on Android 4.4W, Android wear ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.dPad=yes
hw.device.hash2=MD5:f0b5528a2769367d5624a75b0c789fe4
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Android Wear Square
hw.gps=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.keyboard.lid=yes
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.sdCard=no
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
toddbsmithmbp:tools tbsmith$ ./emulator -avd WatchSquare -port 5560 &
[1] 43195
toddbsmithmbp:tools tbsmith$ emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'androidwearsquare'
```

Comment: Google has recently released the official SDK for Android Wear. You should no longer use the preview SDK. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html for instruction on how to set up the emulator.

Comment: I get the same error when I follow these setup intstructions. http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html
I don't see anything new the SDK manager. I don't understand where the new official Wear SDK is. Google searches lead me to these same instruction pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I updated to Android Studio 0.8.2, I deleted my other android-sdk directory in my Downloads folder which I think wasn't being referenced anywhere (but maybe it was looking for skins there) and I deleted API 20W and reinstalled it. Then I deleted and reinstalled the wear AVD. I'm not sure which of these fixed the problem, but now the skins are being found!

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have created this emulator image with the previous public preview, since the article you followed was written before the current SDK was launched.

Try deleting your existing emulator image, and creating a new one. You can also try to create an emulator image with the command line and see if that works:

```
android create avd --force -n WatchRound --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Round" --skin AndroidWearRound --abi android-wear/armeabi-v7a
android create avd --force -n WatchSquare --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Square" --skin AndroidWearSquare --abi android-wear/armeabi-v7a
emulator -avd WatchRound -port 5560 &
emulator -avd WatchSquare -port 5570 &
```

If the command line doesn't work, it means your SDK is somehow corrupted and you might want to delete the old files and redownload them again. It is possible for the previous public preview and current SDK to co-exist.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still can't find the skin. I posted the output from my terminal at the bottom of my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give me a directory listing of $SDK/system-images/android-20/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/skins ... you could use something like this also on OSX: find /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/ -name AndroidWearSquare

Comment: Hmmm, I also notice you are running "Android Studio Beta" from the output above ... are you running the latest 0.8.1?

Comment: I was running 0.8.1 and I just now updated to 0.8.2.

Comment: And here are all the listings of AndroidWearSquare I have: http://pastebin.com/Nt8zS121

Comment: Do you happen to have two copies of Eclipse or Android Studio installed on your machine? I've seen cases where someone had installed Android Studio, created an emulator, then started a different copy of Android Studio and started the emulator from there, and it gave weird behavior like this. I suspect if you were to remove all copies of Android Studio, and remove ~/.android/avd, it would probably fix this up.

Comment: I have one copy of Android Studio and one copy of Eclipse, which I never use. I was able to fix the problem.